# Nginx Gzip compression

Tags: nginx

I have Ubuntu with Nginx installed.  I have not deploy any site and just GET default Nginx static page.

Here is Nginx settings:

```
    ##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

# gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 4;
# gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```

I am checking compression using http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php (my site to test http://demas.me) and it say that the response is not compressed.

Google Developers Tools says:

[image]

Why the compression does not work ?

Thanks

**Updated:**

Full Nginx configuration: http://pastebin.com/D7xjzwAf

Comment: I accessed the site with my browser, and I also got the GZiped response just like LinuxDevOps.

Comment: How do you know that the response is GZiped ?

Comment: Using HTTPFox, I can see that the response headers contain Content-Encoding: gzip -header. I also tested another site with the testing tool you mentioned, and it tells that the site is not sending compressed versions either, although I'm 100% positive it is using compression. So it seems that the online tool doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On testing your site, I find that the response *is* compressed with gzip.

Your screenshot shows a cached response. Clear your browser cache and try again.

As for the tool, the reason it is not getting a compressed response is that it sent an HTTP/1.0 request to your server, rather than an HTTP/1.1 request. By default nginx only sends gzipped responses to HTTP/1.1 requests. (And HTTP/1.1 is over 15 years old, so anything like that that's still sending HTTP/1.0 requests is hopelessly obsolete or broken.)

Answer (score 1):

Your site is accepting gzip/deflate, it looks compressed to me, why so you think differently?

Comment: 1) the site http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php says that it is not compressed 2) YSlow Chrome plugin says that it is not compressed 3) Response Header doesn't include Content-Encoding: gzip header (see Google Chrome Dev screenshoot)

Comment: Response headers do not have `Content-Encoding` header, so the response is not compressed. Did you mean that the client accepts gzip/deflate?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen It was answer to me or to LinuxDevOps ? :)

Comment: (btw I mean to post a comment not an answer). Right, in the screenshot the client accepts gzip but the server is not including Content-Encoding, I can see it though when I make the request:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.4.1 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sat, 22 Mar 2014 17:23:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Mon, 06 May 2013 10:26:49 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip